# SQLite and Android. How do I use String Having in my query?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a query that pulls everything from a database into a list view.

`return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_HEIGHT,
                    KEY_BODY, KEY_HOMEID},null , null, null, null, null,null);`

```
                                |               String Having is the 3rd from
                                                           last null.
```

I want only the records where the field KEY_HOMEID matches a variable called journalId which should be a numeric string.

I would also like to know how to bring the variable into my DatabaseAdapter... 
would `((resource) this.getApplication()).getjournalId())` work?? resource is a class that extends application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, posting error messages rather than "no dice" would be helpful.

Secondly, please read the documentation for [`SQLiteDatabase.query()`](http://bit.ly/bUSRut).  SQL keywords like "FROM" and "HAVING" shouldn't form part of the method call.

You've already passed the table name as the first parameter to `query()`, so writing "`FROM DATABASE_NAME WHERE ...`" is both redundant and will lead to an invalid query being formed.

Thirdly, you can't pass in Java variable names as part of the `selection` parameter String — you need to have a String like: `KEY_HOMEID +"="+ journalId`.

Fourthly, it's generally a good idea to use `selectionArgs` rather than embedding the query parameters into the `selection`.  Especially when you have Strings or parameters coming from user input.
e.g. `selection = KEY_HOMEID +"=?"` and `selectionArgs = new String[] { journalId }`

Overall, your method call should look like:

```
mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, 
          new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_HEIGHT, 
                         KEY_BODY, KEY_HOMEID },
          KEY_HOMEID +"=?", new String[] { journalId },
          null, null, null);
```

Comment: How do I use String Having in my query? in brief how to compare string values in Having clause?

Answer (score 2):

Use a WHERE clause; [HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) is only used with GROUP BY.

Comment: would

SELECT * FROM DATABASE_TABLE WHERE KEY_HOMEID=((resource) this.getApplication()).getjournalId());

work? where should i put it in relation to the query?

Comment: public Cursor fetchAllNotes(String journalId) {
return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_HEIGHT,
                 KEY_BODY, KEY_HOMEID},"FROM DATABASE_TABLE WHERE KEY_HOMEID = journalId",null, null, null, null,null);

thats where i'm at right now still no dice

Comment: `HAVING is only used with Aggregate functions`