# Where clause in sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two application application A and application B. From A I am saving an image, two string values into the database by using contentProvider.

From the application B i am accessing this database and getting the image. The code which i am using is given below

```
byte b[] = null;
Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(allTitles, projection,null, null, null);
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do{
        if(info.activityInfo.name !=   null) {
            if(c.getString(1).equals(info.activityInfo.name)){
                b=c.getBlob(0);
            }
        }
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
c.close();
```

Here in the selection area i am giving null so i am getting all the values in the database and i have to run this loop. Instead of that I want to give a where clause to get the exact raw.

```
Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(allTitles, projection,"activity_name ="+info.activityInfo.name, null, null);
```

So i have changed like this but it does not worked. How i should give the selection args ? Please help.

Comment: Could it be that the `activity_name` column is a text column? In that case you forgot the single quotes around the value. It should be `"activity_name = '" + info.activityInfo.name + "'"`.

Comment: info.activityInfo.name contains the required string value. Will it work ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add WHERE clause to Query on android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271740/how-to-add-where-clause-to-query-on-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try..

```
Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(allTitles, projection,"activity_name = "+info.activityInfo.name, null, null);

or

Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(allTitles, projection,"activity_name = ? ", new String[]{info.activityInfo.name}, null);
```

in case if activity_name is text

```
Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(allTitles, projection,"activity_name = "+"'"+info.activityInfo.name+"'", null, null);

    or

    Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(allTitles, projection,"activity_name = ? ", new String[]{"'"+info.activityInfo.name+"'"+}, null);
```

Comment: The first one is the same which i am using, right ?. I am trying it with the second option.

Comment: "activity_name" is the column name and it is a text type. info.activityInfo.name is variable which contains the text value. So i will try with the second option. Thanks

Comment: Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(allTitles, projection,"activity_name = ?", new String[] {"'"+info.activityInfo.name+"'"}, null); the c.getCount is 0 now. In the database i have the activity name which given in the info.activityInfo.name. Not able to find the reason :-(

Answer (score 0):

You need a '?' for Android to put in values for you in the WHERE clause.
The syntax should be,

Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(allTitles, projection,"activity_name =?", new String[]{info.activityInfo.name}, null);