# how to launch photo gallery with search parameter in Android programatically

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I am trying to programatically launch or open the photo gallery after passing a photo name search parameter.
I am new at this. I am thinking maybe intents can be used but not sure so I am wondering if anyone could please point me in the right direction. Preferably with some code examples.

Much thanks.

RE-EDIT

As requested, this is the code I have so far..

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        // CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 2600;

                        cameraIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture");
```

Comment: anyone have an idea, really need some help!!

Comment: Post some of the code you have written, then the community might be able to provide a more specific solution for you.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically

Comment: hwrdprkins, I have but in my case I just want to provide a file name of string value not uri to actually locate. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try follow code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(photoUri);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean, correct me if I'm wrong:

```
String nameOfPhotoToBeRetrieved = "myPhoto";
String WHERE = "TITLE ="+nameOfPhotoToBeRetrieved;
```

Then you can use the following line to deliver a result to your cursor/listener:

[CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html#setSelection%28java.lang.String%29)(context,[content_uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI),null,[WHERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269863/sqlite-and-android-how-do-i-use-string-having-in-my-query),null,null).deliverResult(myCursor);

Comment: Yes, yes, this is exactly it..could you please provide me a sample code structure for reference? Much much thanks!!